# Django Middleware: Can't get urlredirect to work

Tags: python, django, middleware

So I'm very new to Django, but have completed the tutorials on (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) several times and feel that I'm getting a pretty good handle on it.

The next item I'd like to tackle is creating , installing and configuring middleware (more specifically i'm trying to make it so that when local host accesses the site that it pulls up fine and when someone other than local host pulls it up that it forwards to google.com or some other random site.) I'm mainly doing this for experience building at the request of my boss, so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

I've read the following sites, but can't seem to figure out what to do to get the url redirect to work.

$https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs

$https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/

$http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/510/

Code that I've picked up from the above site (www.djangosnippets.org)

```
import re

from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from django.conf import settings


class UrlRedirectMiddleware:
"""
This middleware lets you match a specific url and redirect the request to a
new url.

You keep a tuple of url regex pattern/url redirect tuples on your site
settings, example:

URL_REDIRECTS = (
    (r'www\.example\.com/hello/$', 'http://hello.example.com/'),
    (r'www\.example2\.com/$', 'http://www.example.com/example2/'),
)

"""
def process_request(self, request):
    host = request.META['HTTP_HOST'] + request.META['PATH_INFO']
    for url_pattern, redirect_url in settings.URL_REDIRECTS:
        regex = re.compile(url_pattern)
        if regex.match(host):
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your settings (assuming you are working with the development server):

e.g

```
URL_REDIRECTS = (
    (r'127.0.0.1:8000/hello', 'http://www.google.com'),
)
```

Also add the `UrlRedirectMiddleware` python-path to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings.

e.g if your `UrlRedirectMiddleware` is defined in a module called `my_middle.py` inside an application called `app`

add `'app.my_middle.UrlRedirectMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`